# Share Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, ntfs

We have some directories on one of our servers that are shared, however, they need to be locked down to an extent that they cannot be accessed by logging on as a local user or administrator or by using the \\server\C$... line.

There are only going to be a select few users that need access to these folders.

Ive read bits about a .htaccess file, however, unable to get it to work.

Help much appreciated!

EDIT: the server that will store the folders is a Windows Server 2008

Comment: More information is going to be needed. You mention .htaccess, is this apache? Are the shares web directories? or what exactly are the shares?

Comment: Hi,The server is a Windows server 2008, and the shares are basic shares on the drives on the server.

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to restrict access to the windows shares on the server. Not to a IIS Website.

Comment: This is a for real question ?

Comment: Um. Isn't .htaccess for Apache web servers?

Answer (score 6):

.htaccess has **nothing** whatsoever to do with Windows File Permissions.

You need to read up on NTFS File & Share (These are different) permissions. That said, attempting to restrict domain and local administrators is fundamentally a lost cause as these can always be overridden.

Comment: If the files only need to be accessed by a single user, then encryption might be an option that cannot be worked around so long as the administrator doesn't install keyboard logger.